# Find a subset of intervals with minimum total cost which together still cover the initial interval

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, shortest-path

Suppose we are given n intervals [xi;yi] for 1 <= i <= n, which together cover an interval [x0;y0]. Each interval [xi;yi] has a positive cost ci. Give an efficient algorithm to find a subset of intervals with minimum total cost which together still cover the interval [x0;y0].

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account. [On topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and ... [the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) apply here.  In particular, show your work so far.

Comment: Solution: https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/9531/finding-the-minimum-subset-of-intervals-covering-the-whole-set